# Running Selenium 2.12 fails on Internet Explorer with Java

Tags: java, internet-explorer, selenium, webdriver

I have just installed the latest version of Selenium 2.12.

I am trying to run the following java program using Selenium on IE. But unfortunately it's not working.

[sample program](http://openwritings.net/public/selenium-2/first-selenium-2-application-java)

Here is the error message.

```
May 24, 2012 7:12:50 PM org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultRequestDirector tryExecute
INFO: Retrying request
Exception in thread "main" org.openqa.selenium.UnhandledAlertException: Modal dialog present (WARNING: The server did not provide any stacktrace information)
Command duration or timeout: 849 milliseconds
Build info: version: '2.21.0', revision: '16552', time: '2012-04-11 19:08:38'
System info: os.name: 'Windows 7', os.arch: 'amd64', os.version: '6.1', java.version: '1.7.0_04'
Driver info: driver.version: InternetExplorerDriver
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Unknown Source)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.ErrorHandler.createThrowable(ErrorHandler.java:175)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.ErrorHandler.throwIfResponseFailed(ErrorHandler.java:134)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.execute(RemoteWebDriver.java:459)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.startSession(RemoteWebDriver.java:140)
    at org.openqa.selenium.ie.InternetExplorerDriver.setup(InternetExplorerDriver.java:113)
    at org.openqa.selenium.ie.InternetExplorerDriver.<init>(InternetExplorerDriver.java:66)
    at ExampleProgram.main(ExampleProgram.java:13)
```

This is launching the IE 8 with the URL "`http://localhost:15194/`" and showing the content - `This is the initial start page for the WebDriver server.`

Please help me with what I'm doing wrong here. I have done the basic setup as mentioned in [wiki](http://code.google.com/p/selenium/wiki/InternetExplorerDriver)

Comment: If you try to use any other page on Internet, say google.com, does it still throw the exception? The exception you see is that there is a modal window opened. Is there any?

Comment: What's the IE version are you using?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This worked for me after installing the new IE version - 9.

Answer (score 1):

Just a small correction, the latest version is 2.21 and not 2.12.

Start your scripts with this

```
driver = Selenium::WebDriver.for :ie, :switches => %w[--ignore-certificate-errors --disable-popup-blocking --disable-translate]
```

Open your browser as an Admin, and change settings in Internet Options to allow popups and also keep "Protected Mode"disabled.

Apart from that, I guess the modal message could also be because there might be some insecure content that is being displayed on a https site.

So to avoid that the message from being displayed, also perform the following steps

- IE-> Open as Admin
- Go to Internet Options
- Go to Security tab
- Click on Custom Level button
- Under Miscellaneous - Enable Mixed content

if this does not solve the issue, please share the exact message that is displayed on the modal popup.
Hope this helps

Comment: I tried these but it did not work out. I updated my question with the exception

Answer (score -1):

You have to download "IEDriverServer_Win32_2.29.0.zip". Extract it to a target folder and instantiate the Internet Explorer browser as below:

```
File file = new File("E:\\Global Blue\\globalblue-selenium-test\\gb-selenium-test\\lib\\IEDriverServer_Win32_2.29.0\\IEDriverServer.exe");
System.setProperty("webdriver.ie.driver", file.getAbsolutePath());
WebDriver oWebDriver = new InternetExplorerDriver();
```

Comment: @ Saulius Šimčikas: still same eror? or what's the error now?

Answer (score -1):

Try using:

```
Thread.sleep(3000);
```

It worked for me.